# How to make a scrollable view? (Samsung Galaxy S menu, Angry Birds Seasons level menu)

Tags: android, layout, view, scrollable

How is this mechanism realized, I mean, having some layouts and changing them when user scrolls the screen? I need it to look like the Samsung Galaxy S main menu, or Angry Birds Seasons level menu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a desktop aplication? Website? Mobile application? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean being able to swipe between different pages of content? If so you can do this using a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) and a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html).

Or if you just mean making a single page of content scrollable you can use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: Thanks, Matt! I've solved this problem using ViewFlipper, it works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the android build in widget named Gallery. Populate the gallery with 3 views and each view with a gridview and there you have it

Answer (score 0):

I would say its just a glorified `ScrollView` containing `ImageButton`s
embed the `ScrollView` in your layout, use the necessary attributes to make the background transparent and hide the scrollbar.  bada-bing bada-boom